# Type error when a generic extends a class

Tags: typescript

This TypeScript code:

```
class Foo {}

function bar<T extends Foo>(): void {
  let value: T = new Foo();
}
```

Gives this error:

```
foo.ts(4,7): error TS2322: Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

This seems wrong to me: `T` extends from `Foo`, so `Foo` should be compatible with `T`

Why does this error happen?

As proof that using `T extends Foo` does work correctly in *some* situations, here is another example which does not give a type error:

```
class Foo {
  protected _foo: number;

  getFoo(): number {
    return this._foo;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  protected _bar: number;
}

function bar<T extends Foo>(a: T) {
  return a.getFoo();
}

bar(new Foo());
bar(new Bar());
```

Note that the `bar` function cannot access any properties on `Bar`, it can only access properties on `Foo`, which is exactly what I expect.

Also note that we are able to assign a value of type `Foo` to type `T`, but only by passing in a `Foo` as an argument, not by using `let a: T = new Foo()`

---

The above code is a very small reduced test case of my much larger application. I am trying to do this:

```
class Foo {
    // Various properties and methods
    protected _foo: number;
}


class Bar extends Foo {
    // Various properties and methods
    protected _bar: number;
}


class Qux<T extends Foo> {
    // Various properties and methods which work on Array<T>
    protected _list: Array<T>;

    get list(): Array<T> {
        // Do initialization / caching / etc.
        return this._list;
    }
}


class Corge<T extends Bar> extends Qux<T> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._list = [new Bar()];
        let value: Array<Bar> = this.list;
    }
}
```

This allows me to put generic methods into `Qux` which work on `Array<Foo>`, and those methods will also work for `Corge`, even though `Corge` uses `Array<Bar>`

But this doesn't work, because of the type error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` extends `Foo`, that means a value of type `T` is assignable to variable of type `Foo`.  Not the other way around.

To use a more concrete example, imagine you have:

```
class FooPlus extends Foo {
    public fooPlusMethod() { }
}

function test<T extends Foo>() {
    let x: T = new Foo();
}

test<FooPlus>();
```

In this case, variable `x` in the function is expected to have type `FooPlus`, and hence you should be able to call `x.fooPlusMethod()`, but you're assigning it a new instance of `Foo`, which wouldn't have that method.

---

And here is the same example based on your own code:

```
let x = new Corge<BarPlus>();
```

Now when I call `x.list`, I expected it to return an `Array<BarPlus>` because it extends `Qux<BarPlus>` which implements that method, but instead I will be getting back an array that will contain an element of type `Bar`, which doesn't implement all the functionality I'd expect from `BarPlus`.

Comment: No, I would not expect to be able to call `x.fooPlusMethod()`, because the signature says that `T` must extend from `Foo`, so within the function the only thing we know about `T` is that it has the same methods as `Foo` (and maybe some additional unknown methods).

Comment: Sorry a bit late to respond. The signature of your class/method is generic, but once you specify it as a type of something, you're telling it a specific `T`.  So here, calling `test<FooPlus>()` says that I'm calling method `test<T>` where `T` *is* `FooPlus`; not just any `T` that extends `Foo`.  Therefore for that invocation, inside the `test<T extends Foo>`, `T` is replaced by `FooPlus`.  Let me know if that's still unclear.

Comment: Take a look at the second example, where I use your own type `Corge` to explain that `x` has type `Corge<BarPlus>` and hence `x.list` will have the type `Array<BarPlus>` (*not* `Array<T extends Bar>`, because T has been specified at this point).  But your code would have returned an `Array<Bar>`, which isn't assignable to `Array<BarPlus>`.

Answer (score 0):

`T` is likely to have additional members, so you can assign value of type `T` to variable of type `Foo` but not the other way around.

Here's example:

```
type Foo = { a: number };
type Bar = { a: number, b: string };

let foo: Foo = { a: 1 };
let bar: Bar = { a: 1, b: '1' };

foo = bar; // OK
bar = foo; // error: "Property 'b' is missing in type 'Foo'"
```

Maybe an easier example:

```
class Shape {
    type: string
}

class Square extends Shape {
    width: number;
}

let shape: Shape = new Square(); //OK
let square: Square = new Shape(); //error - that's what you're trying to do
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not a problem: if a method accepts an argument of type `T extends Foo` then it should only be allowed to use members from `Foo`, because within the method the only thing we know about `T` is that it has `Foo`'s members, we don't know anything else about `T`

Comment: Also, in your answer you demonstrated that it's *okay* to assign a `Bar` to a `Foo`, but my problem is that in my example I *want* to assign a `Bar` to a `Foo`, but I *cannot* because of the type error.

Comment: That's the point - I've explained you why you **can't** assign `new Foo` to `T`. In my example `Bar` is like `T` in yours

Comment: Your new example is still wrong, it's exactly the same as your original example. I do understand subtyping, and my example *should* work correctly. I updated my original question with some further information proving why my code should work.

Comment: How can it work if you're trying to assign value of base type to variable of subtype? `_list` is of type `Array<T>` where `T extends Bar` meaning `T` is a subtype of `Bar`. So back to the shapes example, you're trying to: `let list: Array<Square> = [new Shape()]`

Comment: Please look at my example at the very top. There is no subtyping going on. It is purely about `T extends Foo` not working, even when assigning a value of `Foo` to `T`. As I have demonstrated, assigning a value of type `Foo` to `T` *is* valid, but only when passed as an argument, not when using variables.

Comment: As for my later example, `_list` is of type `Array<Bar>` (because `T extends Bar`), and indeed I am trying to assign it a value of `Array<Bar>`, so it should work. I am *not* trying to assign an `Array<Foo>` to an `Array<Bar>`, why do you keep claiming that?

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand how `T extends Foo` works. When you say `T extends Foo`, you are saying that `T` must be a subtype of `Foo`, *or* it can be `Foo` itself. Or to put it another way, `T extends Foo` means that `T` must have the same properties as `Foo`. It does **not** mean that `T` must be a subtype of `Foo`

Comment: OK, it does not mean that `T` must be a subtype of `Foo`, but you can't guarantee that `T` has no additional members - hence the error

Comment: But it doesn't need to guarantee that `T` has no additional members, because you cannot *access* those additional members, so it's completely safe if `T` does have additional members. As I have *already proven*, my code works completely fine when `T` is an *argument*, but not when it is a *variable*. So any claim you make must deal with the fact that it *does* work with an argument of `T`

Comment: Let's assume there's no error and you've put `new Bar()` into list. Then you can call `get list[0]` returning `T` and you can potentially access not existing members

Comment: You're right: if `Qux` inserts `new Foo()` into `_list`, then `Corge` can use `this._lists[0]` to access it, which is not type safe. If you update your answer, I'll accept it.